# How to import $lib in sveltekit without typescript errors

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, svelte, sveltekit

I would like import a `$lib` for my svelte project without typescript errors in vscode. The project builds and runs without issue.

```
import ThemeSwitch from '$lib/ThemeSwitch/ThemeSwitch.svelte';
```

> Cannot find module '$lib/ThemeSwitch/ThemeSwitch.svelte' or its corresponding type declarations

I am not sure if I need to declare types similar to how svelte declares page data types.

```
/** @type {import('./$types').PageData} */
```

Comment: Have you run `svelte-check`? The question being whether this is an actual code issue or just the editor tooling.

Comment: Running `svelte-check` suggests that this is an editor issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the TS-plugin is enabled in the settings if the import is in a TS/JS file:

```json
{
  "svelte.enable-ts-plugin": true,
}
```

Comment: Awesome, that was the cause. Thanks!

Comment: @Dan, this might be a dumb question, but in which file exactly do I need to add this line?

Comment: @L.Goyal: It's a VS Code setting, if you open the command palette and search `Settings (JSON)` you can edit a workspace or user settings file. You can also find this setting in the UI (search for `Settings (UI)`). If you get errors via `svelte-check`, this will not help you, see comments on question.